# tar extracting on root directory is destroying entire system

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, unix, tar

I'm not sure whats going on... I wasn't aware tar did this. But when I extract a tar on top of the root fs (`/`) with all the permission stuff turned off... for instance:

```
root@system:~# tar --no-same-owner --no-same-permissions --no-overwrite-dir -C / -xzvf test.tar.gz 
./
./lib/
./lib/test
...
```

This precedes to destroy everything in `/usr/bin` (I think)... diagnosed by the most troubling error ever:

```
root@system:~# ls
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
```

The whole OS is pretty much FUBR at this point... I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: I think it depends on what's actually inside `test.tar.gz`...maybe it overwrote / changed permission of the dynamic linker or so? It's probably easier to boot a live medium to find out what's actually happened.

Comment: Btw `--no-same-permissions` (and `--no-same-owner`) might not be what you actually want in such case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many newer Linux distributions (like [Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove) for a long time or [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge) very recently) switched to using symlinks to `/usr` for some base directories. The rationale for this switch is [explained there](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/).

Among the directories replaced with symlinks are:

```
/
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── lib -> usr/lib
├── lib32 -> usr/lib32
├── lib64 -> usr/lib64
├── libx32 -> usr/libx32
├── sbin -> usr/sbin
```

Dearchiving a *tar* archive made from a build system or an install staging area not adhering to the same conventions and that includes not only a file but the directory including this file, will delete the symlink (`--no-overwrite-dir` didn't see a directory but a symlink) having the same name as the directory and write the new directory with its scarce content instead.

So there is a difference when creating the archive of a directory and the archive of the contents of a directory:

```
tar -cf test.tar.gz lib
```

and:

```
tar -cf test.tar.gz lib/*
```

the later won't have a directory in the archive, so won't erase the original symlink when being extracted.

If the former is extracted on a live system, default library path likely won't be able to find libraries in the expected place anymore.

A fix for this on a system where a root shell is still currently available would look like this (on amd64 / x86_64 arch for this example):

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/bin/mv /lib /lib_moved
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/bin/ln -s usr/lib /lib
```

and if needed other similar fixes for other deleted symlinks.