# Obtaining a root shell on a destroyed system

Tags: linux, shell, root

Due to entering ctrl-c during `checkinstall` I am in the state described well by this question: [tar extracting on root directory is destroying entire system](https://superuser.com/questions/1671522/tar-extracting-on-root-directory-is-destroying-entire-system)

However I don't have a root shell open. The commands as listed in the first answer work great otherwise, e.g.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/bin/ls
```

Are there any tricks to get root user at this point? Both sudo and su have errors.

For `su`:
`su: Module is unknown`

For `sudo`:
`sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a filesystem with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges`

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was "surely that can't happen." But sure enough... you're [not the first](https://github.com/giuliomoro/checkinstall/issues/4) to run into this behaviour with `checkinstall`:

> I was packaging libtorrent after having built from source using checkinstall and pressing Ctrl-C during its execution broke my system.
>
> ...
>
> From there, all commands were broken, including bash, ls and sudo.
>
> Not sure why but I believe this is caused by checkinstall wanting to restore an non-existent or wrong backup tar archive.
>
> I had to reboot on a recovery medium to restore the symbolic link from /usr/lib to /lib

Your [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1671522/tar-extracting-on-root-directory-is-destroying-entire-system) mentions that a problematic archive, when extracted over root (`/`), crashed the system:

```
root@system:~# tar --no-same-owner --no-same-permissions --no-overwrite-dir -C / -xzvf test.tar.gz 
./
./lib/
./lib/test
...
```

The impacted user on GitHub also found a spot in `checkinstall` that does a similar thing (extracts to `/`):

> Maybe it is caused by the second Ctrl-C interrupting the first tar command here:
>
> ```
>    echogn "Restoring overwritten files from backup..."
>    cd ${TMP_DIR}/BACKUP
>       files=$(ls -A)
>       $TAR -cpf - $files | $TAR -f - -xvpC / &> /dev/null
>    okfail
> ```

So it is a good bet that fixing the `/lib` symlink would work.

But since you don't have a functioning `sudo` or `su`, I suspect you'll need to boot the system from a recovery environment like a live CD in order to patch up the broken symlink (by moving the empty `/lib` a la `mv /lib /lib_moved` and then re-establishing the symlink a la `ln -s usr/lib /lib`).

The only other ways of gaining root access involve exploits (which likely would not run in a system in this state anyway).